# How to allow third party to extend classes in my java library

Tags: java, inheritance, instantiation

I have a parent class in java with some behavior defined

```
public class ParentClass {
    public ParentClass() {
        //Do some instantiation
    }

    public void doWork() {
       //Do some behavior defined by the parent class
    }
}
```

Now I have some other class in my project that uses this.  Let's say it is used in main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ParentClass parent = new ParentClass();
        parent.doWork();
    }

}
```

Now let's say that my project is setup as a Library for other developers to use.  I want them to be able to extend ParentClass and override the doWork() method to their liking.  If the developer can not change the Main class, how can I assure that ChildClass is instantiated in main() instead of ParentClass?

Example of ChildClass

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public ChildClass() {
        super();
        //Do some more instantiation
    }

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
       super.doWork();
       //Do some more behavior in child class
    }
}
```

Comment: My gut tells me to go with factory method that will somehow know when the developer overrides the ParentClass.  Maybe they will have to tell factory that class i overridden.

Comment: Yep, you need a factory method that can somehow be changed.

Comment: I don't see how that could be "automagic", mainly because if the dev can create one `ParentClass` child then he can create a second one. Maybe you could have a main that take a class name as argument, instantiate that class, check if it's a `ParentClass` child then call `doWork`.

Comment: Are you supplying the developer with `Main` or are they supplying you with things that extend `ParentClass`? I ask because the answer is probably different depending on how `Main` is being used.

Comment: Ideally I want them only to have to extend ParentClass without having to worry about the implementation of Main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you want to achieve, if your library is intended to be used by another 3rd party then most probably your main method would be irrelevant as your JAR package would be bundled in his own JAR, which would only allow for a single main class; his.

This approach may require you to have some trigger to initiate your class (engine?), again, depending on how you intend clients to use your APIs.

Furthermore, you can check the Template Method design pattern as it may be useful for your case, in essence, it allows you to settle the bold lines of your algorithm and define which parts you would like clients to redefine/extend.

Answer (score 1):

Well there seems to be many ways of doing this. One simple way is to have the client pass the name of the child class as a system property. The `main` can access the class name using `System.getProperty("prop.name")`.

Another way is to use the Services API to look for implementing classes. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#the-serviceloader-class.

Having said this, what you described is weird because the client code itself is usually supposed to have its own `main`.

Comment: Main was a bad example.  The idea I was getting at is that I have another class that uses ParentClass and I don't want the developer to have to worry about how ParentClass is being used in this class.  Let me take a look at the service loader, that may be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A library shouldn't have a main class in the first place. Make up your main what it is you're shipping: an application or a library.

Or maybe what you're looking for is the Abstract Factory pattern.

Comment: a main class was just an example, i do not have a main class in the library

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to load a instance of `ParentClass`, but there are some things you need to consider:

- A file needs to be added to the jar that contains the class implementing `ParentClass`, filename `META-INF/services/ParentClass` (replace `ParentClass` with the fully qualified name of the class implemented). For every class implementing `ParentClass` you need to add a line to this file containing the fully qualified name of the implementing class.
- All those classes need to support creating the class with a `public` no-argument constructor.

## Example

### Your jar

```
package mypackage;
// used interface here, since in this case there's no reason to use
// a class
// you could use a class here too
public interface ParentClass {
    public void doWork();
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // execute doWork of every ParentClass provided
        for (ParentClass parent : ServiceLoader.load(mypackage.ParentClass.class)) {
            parent.doWork();
        }
    }

}
```

### jar with implementations of `ParentClass`

```
package mypackage2;

public class ImplementingClass implements ParentClass {

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
       // Custom implementation
       System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

#### META-INF/services/mypackage.ParentClass

```
mypackage2.ImplementingClass
```

Then you only need to add the other jar to your classpath when executing your program.

Answer (score 0):

No need to rely on your provided main method. If they can extend your class they can create an object of their extending class in their *own* main method.